# Check if has passed one day since change happened in a record

Tags: c#

I have been a little confused. I am trying to check the space between the lock date (the field that I use so to know if I need to lock the record for edit) since today. If space is more than a day since DateTime.now then I need to have the ViewBag to true

This is what I have tried so far.

```
    var lockRequest = from t in _context.Request
                        
                         where t.Condition == 2

                         select t;

        foreach (var t in lockRequest)
        {
            if (DateTime.Now.Day - Convert.ToDateTime(t.RequestLockDate).Day > 1 )

            {
                ViewBag.isLocked = true;


            }
            else
            {
                ViewBag.isLocked = false;

            }

        }
```

But it doesn't work it always returns to true. Any idea? thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [`Day` property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.day?view=net-5.0) of `DateTime`:

> Gets the day of the month represented by this instance.

ie

> The day component, expressed as a value between 1 and 31.

So one place your code could fail is from one month to the next when the counter resets.

You could instead subtract one `DateTime` from the other to give you a resulting `TimeSpan`, then look to see how long that is:

```
if ((DateTime.Now - Convert.ToDateTime(t.RequestLockDate)).TotalHours > 24) {
    ViewBag.isLocked = true;
} else {
    ViewBag.isLocked = false;
}
```

or just

```
ViewBag.isLocked = (DateTime.Now - Convert.ToDateTime(t.RequestLockDate)).TotalHours > 24;
```

Answer (score 2):

Comparing Day property might give you wrong result just imagine 31.1.2020 and 1.2.2020

I would suggest comparing datetimes

```
var locked = Datetime.Today.AddDays(-1) > t.RequestLockDate
```

Comment: Why is a `TimeSpan` "not what you expect"? They want to know elapsed time, which is what one of those is made for.

Comment: @Pribina Whatever unit you want it as.  `TimeSpan` has multiple properties to get the info out however you wish.

Comment: i agree with guys but he compares it without using any property straight with 1 as integer

Comment: I suggest to remove that  part from the answer. Keep explanation of why using only Days is bad and suggested solution (it's better than @JamesThorpe one).

Answer (score 0):

This would be how the check would be done:

```
    var currentDate = DateTime.Now;
    var newDate = t.RequestLockDate;
    
    var isPreviousDay = (currentDate - newDate).TotalDays >= 1;
    Console.WriteLine(isPreviousDay);
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried it this way ?

```
if ((DateTime.Now - Convert.ToDateTime(t.RequestLockDate)) > TimeSpan.FromDays(1))
{
    ViewBag.isLocked = true;
}
else
{
    ViewBag.isLocked = false;
}
```